# Heroku ACM SSL - ACM failing for non www domain

Tags: heroku, heroku-ssl

I have an existing Rails application in Heroku. I configured ACM SSL for the application this evening and everything worked fine. After an hour, I received an email stating that the ACM failed for the non "www" domain. Everything works fine for www.

Is the non-www domain required? We enforce a 301 redirect on the domain to use www version.

Am I missing something? Help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I getting same error. You fix that?